# Why do textbooks prefer "++x" to "x++" when it is context invariant?

Tags: c++, post-increment, pre-increment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between i++ and ++i in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484462/difference-between-i-and-i-in-a-loop) 
>   [Is there a performance difference between i++ and ++i in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c) 
>   [Incrementing in C++ - When to use x++ or ++x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812990/incrementing-in-c-when-to-use-x-or-x) 
>   [Why use ++i instead of i++ in cases where the value is not used anywhere else in the statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392820/why-use-i-instead-of-i-in-cases-where-the-value-is-not-used-anywhere-else-in)

Why in C++ textbooks is there a preference for writing `++x`  rather than `x++` when this occurs in a context where the pre/post nature doesn't matter ?

In general, it seems that actions are given in object,verb order

eg:

`foo.size()`   is the 'object' `foo` , with 'verb' `size`

`a + b`  is 'object' `a` , with verb `+`

In EXCEL you always select the object , then specify the action (verb).

note : Lotus 1-2-3 did things in verb-object order which caused enormous problems for people who had developed muscle memory in the 123 to XL transition...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between i++ and ++i in a loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484462/difference-between-i-and-i-in-a-loop) and especially [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/484492/103167)  Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c

Comment: I wouldn't call it a duplicate since he is asking in general since and not in just loops.

Comment: You should really read a beginner's guide to C++. Analogies to Excel won't help you much.

Comment: Because if your compiler was really stupid, `i++` would needlessly store a temporary copy of `i`. It isn't, so it doesn't matter, but that's why `++i` was accepted as the best practice.

Comment: @yamikoWebs: How about [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c) then?

Comment: They do it for consistency: it matters a lot with iterators, so they keep using `++x` everywhere else for the code samples in their books to look consistent.

Comment: No -- this recognises the difference.  But asks why there is an apparent preference when the difference doesn't matter.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin I never read that before in any of my c++ textbooks. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer `++x` over `x++` because, to me, it emphasizes the increment operation over the name of the variable.  It's strictly a matter of preference, but I think it highlights my intention more clearly.

More important is that you choose one or the other and use it consistently.  Code that's peppered with `++x` and `x++` used arbitrarily when their effect is identical is just a recipe for unmaintainability.  Sooner or later, someone's going to "fix" it to be consistent, and they'll probably introduce bugs when they change an instance that really *does* matter.

Answer (score 3):

i++ will create a copy of the object i. If i is a complex iterator, this may reduce performance considerably, compared to ++i.

Comment: That's the historical reason, but it really doesn't apply nowadays.

Comment: There is usually only a performance difference in Debug mode.

Comment: What about if there are side effects?