# Optimizing recursive method

Tags: java, optimization, recursion

I have some code that needs to run with some rather large numbers, and it involves incrementing into a recursive method and is therefor very slow to the point where I can't even get to my desired answer.  Could someone help me optimize it?  I am a beginner though, so I can't do anything very complex/difficult.

```
public class Euler012{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        int divisors=0;
        for(long x=1;divisors<=501;x++){
            divisors=1;
            long i=triangle(x);
            for(int n=1;n<=i/2;n++){
                if(i%n==0){
                    divisors++;
                }
            }
            //System.out.println(divisors+"\n"+ i);
            System.out.println(i+": " + divisors);
        }
    }
    public static long triangle(long x){
        long n=0;
        while(x>=0){
            n+=x;
            x--;
            triangle(x);
        }
        return n;
    }
 }
```

Comment: What is triangle(x) supposed to return? The recursive call in it seems like a bug, since you are always calling it with the same x value, so it will cause an infinite recursion.

Comment: @Eran - The value is decremented just before the recursive call.

Comment: @DonRoby Oh, I see. But, still, OP doesn't do anything with the return value of `triangle`, so what's the point of the recursive call?

Comment: @Eran - That's true and likely part of his problem.

Comment: @Eran the function returns the next "triangle" number in the sequence.  (with the return statement after the while loop).  A triangle number n is the summation of every number up to and including n.

Comment: I would like to know what your program should do and you don't need the >= check in your while condition > is enough

Comment: If you are concerned about optimisation, you can go for the O(1) approach and use the function 

`public static long triangle(long x){
return (x*x + x)/2;
}`

Comment: @RichardKennethNiescior could you please explain your function?  I'm not sure I understand how that is the same as my triangle method

Comment: @seth Fundamentally your triangle method is a summation of a dynamic value being decremented by one as it approaches zero. So, lets take this for example, `triangle(5)` is O(5) as it requires 5 iterations to complete the computation, thus it would be the following process (5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1) == 15 right? It runs through multiple instructions where as the suggestion I provided, gives you O(1) instance where there are **no redundant iterations** as ((5 * 5 + 5)/2) == 15. Get the picture? It is about minimising the number of instructions required to perform the computation.

Comment: @seth it is the same, its the gaussian summation formula - dont know the correct name in english. You can test the formular with a few numbers and i can proof it if you want

Comment: Thank you everyone!  You have all been incredibly helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: i don't think its an optimization problem, because its a small task, but as mentioned in the comments you do many unnecessary things.

Ok, now lets see where you can optimize things:

#### recursion

recursion has usually a bad performance, especially if you don't save values this would be possible in your example.

e.g.: **recursive triangle-number function with saving values**

```
private static ArrayList<Integer> trianglenumbers = new ArrayList<>();

public static int triangleNumber(int n){
    if(trianglenumbers.size() <= n){
        if(n == 1)
            trianglenumbers.add(1);
        else
            trianglenumbers.add(triangleNumber(n-1) + n);
    }
    return trianglenumbers.get(n-1);
}
```

but as mentioned by @RichardKennethNiescior you can simply use the formula:
`(n² + n)/2`

but here we can do optimization too!
you shouldnt do `/2` but rather `*0.5` or even `>>1`(shift right)
but most compilers will do that for you, so no need to make your code unreadable

#### your main method

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    int divisors = 0; //skip the = 0
    for(long x=1;divisors<=501;++x){ // ++x instead of x++
        divisors=0;
        long i=(x*x + x) >> 1; // see above, use the one you like more
        /*how many divisors*/
        if(i == 1) divisors = 1;
        else{ /*1 is the only number with just one natural divisor*/
            divisors = 2; // the 1 and itself
            for(int n = 2; n*n <= i; ++n){
                if(n*n == i) ++divisors;
                else if(i%n == 0) divisors += 2;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(i+": " + divisors);
    }
}
```

the ++x instead of x++ thing is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392820/why-use-i-instead-of-i-in-cases-where-the-value-is-not-used-anywhere-else-in?answertab=votes#tab-top)

the how many divisors part:
every number except 1 has at least 2 divisors (primes, the number itself and one)
to check how many divisors a number has, we just need to go to the root of the number
(eg. 36 -> its squareroot is 6)
36 has 9 divisors (4 pares) {1 and 36, 2 and 18, 3 and 12, 4 and 8, 6 (and 6)}

1 and 36 are skiped (`for(**int n = 2**)`) but counted in `divisors = 2`
and the pares 2, 3 and 4 increase the number of divisors by 2
and if its a square number (n*n == i) then we add up 1

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to generate a new triangle number from scratch each time, if you save the value to a variable, and then add x to it on the next iteration, you dont really need to have the triangle method at all.